# Why can I call a monadic function without supplying a monad?

Tags: haskell, monads, state-monad

I thought I had a good handle on Haskell Monads until I realized this very simple piece of code made no sense to me (this is from the [haskell wiki about the State monad](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/State_Monad)):

```
playGame :: String -> State GameState GameValue
playGame []     = do
  (_, score) <- get
  return score
```

What confuses me is, why is the code allowed to call "get", when the only argument supplied is a string? It seems almost like it is pulling the value out of thin air.

A better way for me to ask the question may be, how would one rewrite this function using `>>=` and lambda's instead of do notation? I'm unable to figure it out myself.

Comment: Code isn't "calling" get.  "get" isn't a function, it's a polymorphic value: http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/transformers/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad-Trans-State-Lazy.html#v:get

Comment: Thanks, that was actually a major point of confusion for me. It's almost an unfortunate name for someone coming from the OO world where classes typically have "getThis" and "getThat" methods. I just assumed that since "get" is a verb, it must be a function.

Comment: It's not that simple, even in OO land.  Especially since OO getters are not functions -- they are actually much closer to polymorphic values, just like Haskell's get is.  The difference is that the monad in OO languages attaches the value to an object, whereas we attach the value to arbitrary monads with arbitrary semantics.  I'll make an answer explaining what I mean.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Desugaring this into `do` notation would look like

```
 playGame [] =
   get >>= \ (_, score) ->
   return score
```

We could also just write this with `fmap`

```
 playGame [] = fmap (\(_, score) -> score) get
 playGame [] = fmap snd get
```

Now the trick is to realize that `get` is a value like any other with the type

```
 State s s
```

What `get` will return won't be determined until we feed our computation to `runState` or similar where we provide an explicit starting value for our state.

If we simplify this further and get rid of the state monad we'd have

```
playGame :: String -> (GameState -> (GameState, GameValue))
playGame [] = \gamestate -> (gamestate, snd gamestate)
```

The state monad is just wrapping around all of this manual passing of `GameState` but you can think of `get` as accessing the value that our "function" was passed.

Comment: So in a sense, the State monad is hiding the passing of the state (as you mentioned). I can appreciate the "magic" here. But surely in the guts of runState is where the value of "get" is "held"... right?

Comment: @parker.sikand So `State` is just a wrapper on top of a literal function `s -> (s, a)`. `runState` is what we use to actually *apply* this function. You can think of it as a sort of "souped-up" `$`. So I suppose `runState` holds the value of `get` as much as in `(\x -> ...) $ a` `$` holds the value of `x`

Answer (score 1):

A monad is a "thing" which takes a context (we call it m) and which "produces" a value, while still respecting the monad laws.  We can think of this in terms of being "inside" and "outside" of the monad.  The monad laws tell us how to deal with a "round trip" -- going outside and then coming back inside.  In particular, the laws tell us that m (m a) is essentially the same type as (m a).

The point is that a monad is a generalization of this round-tripping thing.  join squashes (m (m a))'s into (m a)'s, and (>>=) pulls a value out of the monad and applies a function into the monad.  Put another way, it applies  a function (f :: a -> m b) to the a in (m a) -- which yields an (m (m b)), and then squashes that via join to get our (m b).

So what does this have to do with 'get' and objects?

Well, do notation sets us up so that the result of a computation is in our monad.  And (<-) lets us **pull** a value out of a monad, so that we can bind it to a function, while still nominally being inside of the monad.  So, for example:

```
doStuff = do
   a <- get
   b <- get
   return $ (a + b)
```

Notice that a and b are pure.  They are "outside" of the get, because we actually peeked inside it.  But now that we have a value outside of the monad, we need to do something with it (+) and then stick it back in the monad.

This is just a little bit of suggestive notation, but it might be nice if we could do:

```
doStuff = do
  a       <- get
  b       <- get
  (a + b) -> (\x -> return x)
```

to really emphasize the back and forth of it.  When you finish a monad action, you *must* be on the right column in that table, because when the action is done, 'join' will get called to flatten the layers.  (At least, conceptually)

Oh, right, objects.  Well, obviously, an OO language basically lives and breathes in an IO monad of some kind.  But we can actually break it down some more.  When you run something along the lines of:

```
 x = foo.bar.baz.bin()
```

you are basically running a monad transformer stack, which takes an IO context, which produces a foo context, which produces a bar context, which produces a baz context, which produces a bin context.  And then the runtime system "calls" join on this thing as many times as needed.  Notice how well this idea meshes with "call stacks".  And indeed, this is why it is called a "monad transformer stack" on the haskell side.  It is a stack of monadic contexts.